# Variable value inside Jenkins Pipeline script sh command

Tags: shell, if-statement, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a Jenkins script, and I am having trouble resolving one command. There is this `if` statement which checks for the existence of a remote directory and if it is available, it will provide permissions for  the same and if not it will return failure. The problem is that, a part of the directory path is derived using a variable and that variable is being referenced as `$variable_name`. The problem I am facing is, that variable is either coming as a complete string or it is getting an empty value inside the if command. When we check the value outside using `echo`, it is returning the correct value.
The following is a piece of my code:

```
def myversion ="${params.VersionName}"
pipeline {
  agent { label 'example' }
    stages {
      stage('Testing Stage') {
         steps {
            script { 
                sh "echo '${myversion}'"
                sh '''if sshpass -p remote_user_password ssh remote_user_name@remote_user_address '[ -d "some_path_here-${myversion}/Mac" ]'; then 
sshpass -p remote_user_password ssh remote_user_name@remote_user_address "echo remote_user_password | sudo -S chmod -R 777 some_path_here-${myversion}/Mac"
else
    echo "failure"
fi'''
                  }
                }
             }
          }
      }
```

And the console output is

```
echo test
test
[Pipeline] sh
+ sshpass -p remote_user_password ssh remote_user_name@remote_user_address [ -d "some_path_here-${myversion}/Mac" ]
+ echo failure
failure
```

From the console output, I can see the `${myversion}` coming as it is rather than the passed parameter which is '**test**'
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after many different tweaking attempts, got a solution here:
Eventhough the Jenkins Pipeline syntax generator is capable of generating Jenkins script, it may not be always helpful. In this case, I had to use double quotes instead of single quotes and modify the internal `-d` command. Finally here is a working code:

```
def myversion ="${params.VersionName}"
pipeline {
  agent { label 'example' }
    stages {
      stage('Testing Stage') {
         steps {
            script { 
                sh "echo '${myversion}'"
                sh """if sshpass -p remote_user_password ssh remote_user_name@remote_user_address '[ -d some_path_here-${myversion}/Mac ]'; then 
sshpass -p remote_user_password ssh remote_user_name@remote_user_address 'echo remote_user_password | sudo -S chmod -R 777 some_path_here-${myversion}/Mac'
else
    echo 'failure'
fi"""
                  }
                }
             }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change single quotas to double outside sh command:

```
def myversion ="${params.VersionName}"
pipeline {
  agent { label 'example' }
    stages {
      stage('Testing Stage') {
         steps {
            script { 
                sh "echo '${myversion}'"
                sh """if sshpass -p remote_user_password ssh remote_user_name@remote_user_address '[ -d "some_path_here-${myversion}/Mac" ]'; then 
sshpass -p remote_user_password ssh remote_user_name@remote_user_address "echo remote_user_password | sudo -S chmod -R 777 some_path_here-${myversion}/Mac"
else
    echo "failure"
fi"""
                  }
                }
             }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had single quotes and once I switched it to double quotes, my shell line doing scp now was able to use the variable.

`REMOTE_HOSTS.split(',').each {def REMOTE_HOST = "${it}" def REMOTE_USER_HOST = "${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_HOST}"                           sh "echo Deploy to remote host: ${REMOTE_USER_HOST}" sh "scp deploy.sh $REMOTE_USER_HOST:~/" }`